# aws redshift - identity column maximum limit

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table where I am thinking to create identity column for auto sequence generation for a fact table. what is the maximum value an identity column can be ?

Answer (score 1):

An identity column can be either INT (2^31 - 1) or BIGINT (2^63 - 1).  So with the BIGINT identity column the max value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.